# Not able to access windows partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

Whenever I am clicking on windows drive I am getting this error as in screenshot here:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The error says it all: Windows is hibernated. It's not safe to write to the windows partition. You can either shut down windows (meaning: boot to windows and really shut it down), mount the windows partition read only (you have to do this on the command line), or delete the hibernation information of Windows (again: command line), meaning that it will boot up freshly next time you try to start it (and, oh wonder, your running session in Windows will be lost, including not yet saved files). My suggestion is therefore: Resume Windows, save your files, and shut down Windows, don't use hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for your help...You should have submitted this as an answer...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into windows, try shutting down. Then try mounting.
If that doesn't help, try restarting windows and select ubuntu from the boot screen

Comment: Thanx man for your help :)